# Books on third-order logic and above.

Tags: logic

I was wondering if anyone knows where I could get books on third-order predicate logic, in order to learn third order logic. I searched bookstores and Google everywhere I could think. I am also interested in fourth-order and so on. thanks

or
Could someone try explaining it to me in plain English with examples.

Comment: "Higher order logic" most commonly goes under the name 'set theory'.

Comment: Nothing special about 3rd-order and on; the treatment is the same for 2nd-order. See e.g. S.Shapiro, [Foundations Without Foundationalism: A Case for Second-Order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=1ZIUDAAAQBAJ&pg=PR19), M.Fitting, [Types, Tableaus, and Gödel’s God](https://books.google.it/books?id=mP70CAAAQBAJ&pg=PR5), P.Andrews, [An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=UaPuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA201).